# nghttp2-asio : Proper way to set content-type in header

Tags: c++, nghttp2

I came up with this code, but not sure if it is right usage:

```
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    nghttp2::asio_http2::header_map headers;
    headers.insert(std::pair<std::string, nghttp2::asio_http2::header_value>("content-type", {"application/json; charset=utf-8", false}));
    headers.insert(std::pair<std::string, nghttp2::asio_http2::header_value>("content-length",{std::to_string(r.length()), false}));

    auto req = session->submit(ec, "POST", uri, r.data(), headers);
```

Could anybody tell me if this is correct usage.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you have done is correct way of setting a header in `nghttp2 asio`. Please read the documentation to know the usage of the `sensitive` field [here](https://nghttp2.org/documentation/asio_http2.h.html).

For brevity, you can use `std::make_pair`. For example:

`headers.insert(std::make_pair("content-type", {"application/json; charset=utf-8", false}));`